# DataTable : How to hide table header?

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have 2 tables using DataTable :

- top: exact match
- bottom : related

Here is what they look like right now.

[image]

As you can see that, there is no need to show the table header on the second table. I want to hide it.

I have tried using this on my CSS :

Since the class = `inventory_related`

```
.inventory_related table thead {

        display:none;

    }
```

I also tried to take off the whole :

```
       <thead class="thin-border-bottom ">

            <th>Catalog # </th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Available Vials</th>

        </thead>
```

This doesn't work either.

Anyone have any suggestion on how do I hide my 2nd table header ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the class name `inventory_related` on the `<table>`? If so, you need `table.inventory_related thead` (but its better to omit the element and write `.inventory_related thead`)

Comment: <table class="display" id="inventory_related" class="inventory_related">

Comment: You can only have one `class`attribute on a table. Change to `<table class="display inventory_related" id="inventory_related">`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to. It should be like this `<table class="display inventory_related" id="inventory_related" >`

Answer (score 19):

In my case, setting

```
.inventory_related thead {    
    display:none;   
}
```

messed with column widths, while

```
.inventory_related thead {    
    visibility: collapse;   
}
```

seems to be working.

Answer (score 5):

```
<table>
  <thead style='display:none;'>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>row value 1</td>
    <td>row value 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please see the following code as an example:

```css
.inventory_related thead {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>header 1</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>row value 1</td>
    <td>row value 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class='inventory_related'>
  <thead>
    <th>header</th>
    <th>header 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>row value 3</td>
    <td>row value 4</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I was wondering , how can i hide selected column header and column data.

Comment: @parladneupane You should probably start a new question with the details that you need.

Answer (score 0):

if the class of `<table>` is `inventory_related` then write the following css

```
.inventory_related thead {    
    display:none;   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it in jQuery(js) then you  can simply do:

```
$("#datatableId").css("display", "none");
```

where 'datatableId' is the ID of your table or some div tag which contains the table.