# DataTable print function - How to hide or remove the title and set the filename?

Tags: jquery, datatables

How do I hide or remove the title from the page I print and set the filename when I save the file into PDF or xps?

```
$('#report').dataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'print',
    title: 'I want to hide this but use it as my filename when I save it.'
  }]
});
```

Comment: CSS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593598/datatable-how-to-hide-table-header

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think I can hide the title using the css because it does not has class or id. If table, maybe yes.

Comment: If you had posted a [mcve] we could have checked. Right click on the title on the table - inspect- and look at the class in the console

Comment: @mplungjan here is the live test data: http://live.datatables.net/diyufuba/1/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`('#report').dataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'print',
    title: 'Filename here.',
    customize: function ( win ) {
      $(win.document.body).children("h1:first").remove();
    }
  }]
});`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the bellow sample code

```
$('#report').dataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
    extend: 'print',
    title: ''
  },
{
    extend: 'pdf',
    title: 'your file name'
  },
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave 'title' as empty...

```
$('#datatable').DataTable( {
   buttons: [
               { 
                  extend: 'excel',
                  text: 'Download Excel',
                  title: ''
                }
            ]
});
```